# Find length of sequence with fibonacci principle

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Let assume we have sequence:

$${l_{n + 1}} = {l_n} + {l_{n - 1}}
$$

$$\begin{array}{l}{l_0} = 0\\{l_1} = 01\\{l_2} = 010\end{array}$$

Our goal to get $|{l_n}|$ (length). For ${l_0}$ it's 0, for ${l_1}$ it's 2, e.t.c.

I have the solution:

- Select solution with form ${m^n} = {l_n}$

$$ 
{m^n} = {l_{n+1}} - {l_{n-1}}
\\
{m^{n+1}} = {m^n} + {m^{n-1}}
\\
m^2 = m+1
$$

- Find ${m_1}, {m_2}$ , it will be golden section numbers
- Space dimension of ${l_n}$ is 2(first two elemtns, it's clear for me)
- Common solution is ${c_1}{m_1}^n+{c_2}{m_2}^n $
- Then we can find ${C_1} , {C_2}$ from system equitions:

$$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{c_1}{m^0}_1 + {c_2}{m^0}_2 = 1}\\{{c_1}{m^1}_1 + {c_2}{m^1}_2 = 2}\end{array}} \right.
$$

- It's cool and it works!

**My questions:**

- Why Common solution is ${c_1}{m_1}^n+{c_2}{m_2}^n $ ?
- Space dimension is two, so in my mind: ${l_n}$ can be write as linear combination of basis, i.e. ${l_n}={k_1}{m_1} + {k_2}{m_2}$ why not?